# SSRS Report Viewer 10.0.0.0 Error

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2014

From my application, the user clicks a button that launches a new window that contains the Report Viewer control and from there the user chooses the parameters from dynamically generated dropdown lists. When they click the View Report button it will occasionally throw the following error:

```
"The report execution {random ID code that changed with each error} has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)"
```

After doing some Google research, I've tried:

1. Trimming all white space from the report path.
2. Extending the session time out on the server.
3. Making sure the time zones were the same on both the SSRS server and the SQL server.
4. Remove the session variable that equals "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy".

None of these solutions have fixed the problem. I have not been able to figure out what causes the error to show up. It seems to get thrown at random times.

Has anyone run into this error and figured out what causes it/how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the log file on the reporting server to obtain more detailed info. The log file is created in [PROGRAM_FILES]\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles. If you can isolate the conditions and reproduce the problem then you can more than likely find more info on what is causing the issue. I would bet this is an issue when a report is requested and your application's session has not expired but the session between you app, the reportviewer, and ssrs has expired. You can increase that value.